# how to detect if ptrace already called in golang linux

Tags: go, ptrace

I am learning golang and I wanna implement a simple Linux anti-debugging method in golang. I have a CPP code which works in the same way I intended. But cannot do the same in golang. can you guys guide me how to do same in go?

Here is the C++ Code I am using as a reference.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>


bool isBeingTraced(){
    return ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, 1, 0) == -1;
}

int main()
{
    if (isBeingTraced()) 
    {
        printf("don't trace me !!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Not being traced...  (maybe)\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And I wanna do the same thing in go lang.
Is it even possible to do the same in go?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    if isBeingTraced() {
        fmt.Println("don't trace me !!")
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Not being traced...  (maybe)")
}

func isBeingTraced() bool {
    return true // How to Implement that Cpp Function here?
}
```

Comment: I hope you know that these "anti tracing" attempts are quite defeatable and will do *nothing* to deter a skilled attacker...

Comment: Yap @JesperJuhl I know it. It can be bypassed by a simple breakpoint. I am just learning golang and trying to implement it as an experiment.

Comment: one possible way I have found is to use cgo and call that C function. But I wanna do it in a golang way.

Comment: Here's how the standard library calls it: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/syscall/exec_linux.go#L511 .

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thank you so much. It is working as expected after a bit tweaking. _, _, res := syscall.RawSyscall(syscall.SYS_PTRACE, uintptr(syscall.PTRACE_TRACEME), 0, 0)

Comment: @MarkPlotnick But after Doing This. All exec.Command() seems to stopped working.  It is just getting stuck without any errors. the program seems to be stopped altogether. But when I am trying to debug the program using gdb, It started working as before. Starting the program using debugger or strace, seems to make this code run smoothly.

Comment: When you call `ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME)`, whether in C or Go, it tells the kernel that your parent process is willing to handle events that will put the debugee process into ptrace-stop state. That includes execs and receipt of a signal. gdb can handle events like this. I haven't met a shell than can handle events like this. PTRACE_TRACEME isn't reversible; programs that use it for anti-debugging ought to just print an error message and exit.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I didn't knew about it before. Well Is There any way to get it working?

Comment: I haven't thought about it. Maybe you can ask a new question with the additional conditions you want - being able to do an exec after the PTRACE_TRACEME - and someone else may be able to help.

Comment: As for this question, please consider answering it yourself (in the text box near the bottom of this page) with the go code that you have written. I think it will be helpful to other people.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thank you so much for your help dude! Sure I'll post an answer for this. Thanks again!

Comment: I looked into this a little more. It's not the `execve` system call that pauses the debuggee - the go runtime does a `spawn` first and the execve is in a different thread. Rather, it's the `SIGCHLD` that the debuggee receives while in `exec.Command`, specifically while in `os.(*Process).blockUntilWaitable`. Adding a call to Ignore SIGCHLD doesn't change the outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @MarkPlotnick's comments, here is the golang Equivalent code for the c++ code posted by me.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    if isBeingTraced() {
        fmt.Println("don't trace me !!")
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Not being traced...  (maybe)")
}

func isBeingTraced() bool { 
    _, _, res := syscall.RawSyscall(syscall.SYS_PTRACE, uintptr(syscall.PTRACE_TRACEME), 0, 0)
    return res == 1
}
```

Ref: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/syscall/exec_linux.go#L511

But the problem I have been with this code is, You cannot call exec.Command() after calling PTRACE_TRACEME.
Will try to find a solution to this problem. and if I got any, I will reference it here.